# cmake, qt, different libraries and executable. Localization?

Tags: c++, qt, localization, internationalization, cmake

I have a project build by myself that is made by different executable and different libraries.

The idea is like:

```
/Src/
     ExecA/CMakeLists.txt
     ExecB/CMakeLists.txt
     LibC/CMakeLists.txt
     LibD/CMakeLists.txt
```

ExecA uses LibC and LibD,
ExecB uses only LibC
or... let me say... not all the executables uses all the libraries.

I have written in every CMakeLists.txt this sentence that allow me to generate ts and qm files:

```
SET(LANGUAGES ${SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)
SET(LANGUAGE_TS_FILES)
FOREACH(LANGUAGE ${LANGUAGES})
    SET(TS_FILE      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${LIBRARY_NAME}_${LANGUAGE}.ts")
    SET(LANGUAGE_TS_FILES ${LANGUAGE_TS_FILES} ${TS_FILE})
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${TS_FILE} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
 ENDFOREACH(LANGUAGE ${LANGUAGES})
 IF(LANGUAGE_TS_FILES) 
     QT4_CREATE_TRANSLATION(qm_files ${FILES} ${QMLFILES}      ${LANGUAGE_TS_FILES})
 ENDIF(LANGUAGE_TS_FILES)
```

The qm files are then loaded in a qrc file that is shipped.
library:

```
set(RESOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/translations_${LIBRARY_NAME}.qrc
)
```

executable:

```
set(RESOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/translations_${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.qrc
 )
```

when create the library I have a sentence like

```
add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} ${FILES} ${HEADERS} ${HEADERS_MOC}   {RESOURCES} ${qm_files})
```

and for the executable:

```
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${FILES} ${HEADERS} ${HEADERS_MOC} ${RESOURCES} ${qm_files} LibA LibB)
```

with this code I am able to generate ts files, I edit them and then I can generate qm files to be loaded when the application starts.
The problem I am facing is that only the code present in the application is localized. The code of the library is not localized.

I read that I have to directly load translation for the library but, everywhere I try to load the qm file from the qrc with:

```
myappTranslator.load(langstr);
```

I receive a false as reply for all the qm files of the libraries.
It works for the executable.

Any hint on investigting on how to have libraries localized?